# Get PHP MySQL PDO column table name as a result of a join

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have fields that have the same name in different tables that I'm joining. Such as `ticket.status`, `user.status` and `transaction.status`. At the moment the query returns just `status`.

How can I get the table name in such a way that it stops similar field names from overwriting and so I can tell the difference between the fields.

Simply put:

```
$data = array($eventId);
$statement = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ticket, user, transaction 
                        WHERE ticket.eventId = ? 
                        AND ticket.userId = user.userId
                        AND ticket.transactionId = transaction.transactionId");

$statement->execute($data); 
$rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

In my research I've found the constant `PDO::ATTR_FETCH_TABLE_NAMES` that looks like it could help, but I do not know how to implement ( I assume through `$statement->setAttribute();` somehow).

I also have concerns that it will not work, as the PHP documentation mentions it is dependent on the driver.

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible for you to stop using `SELECT *` and instead do `SELECT ticket.status AS ticket_status, user.status AS user_status, ...`?

Comment: p.s I'm not 100% sure but I think doing what you do in `where` instead of actually `join` is slower.

Comment: @SeanBright, yes but I did try that and it does not solve the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add new aliases to your select statements

```
$statement = $this->db->prepare("
    SELECT *, ticket.status AS ticket_status, user.status AS user_status, transaction.status AS transaction_status 
    FROM ticket, user, transaction 
    WHERE ticket.eventId = ? 
    AND ticket.userId = user.userId
    AND ticket.transactionId = transaction.transactionId
");
```

Then you can do

```
$rows[0]['user_status'];
$rows[0]['ticket_status'];
$rows[0]['transaction_status'];
```

If you are really concern by performance, the quantity of data returned will be greater so instead of adding new aliases you can select every single columns and while you do so put an alias on the `status` column.

Comment: This is true, trying it now.

Answer (score 1):

Why not change your to actually join instead:

```
SELECT 
t.status as ticket_status, u.status as user_status, tr.status as trans_status
FROM 
ticket as t
inner join user as u on t.userId = u.userId
inner join transaction as tr on t.transactionId = tr.transactionId
where
t.eventId = ?
```

You don't even need to cast the tables using `as something` but I find it's neater.

Note, its the casting of the columns that will actually fix this issue, not the join method.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious comment is "don't do it, that's why aliases exist". But there's still a good underlying question: does MySQL send information about where a result-set column comes from (table, view or calculated)?

Apparently, it does, since the `PDOStatement` object has an experimental method called [getColumnMeta()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php). I've been testing and it returns an associative array where the `table` key

- contains the source table if column comes from a table or view
- is an empty string if the column is calculated

Of course, I'd stick to aliases anyway. Being able to use associative arrays is a killer feature for me.